# Count and name content from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which is structured like this:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------------------+
| id  |    name     |        timestamp        |
+-----+-------------+-------------------------+
| 1   | someName    | 2016-04-20 09:41:41.213 |
| 2   | someName    | 2016-04-20 09:42:41.213 |
| 3   | anotherName | 2016-04-20 09:43:41.213 |
| ... | ...         | ...                     |
+-----+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Now, I am trying to create a query, which selects all timestamps since time x and count the amount of times the same name occurs in the result.

As an example, if we would apply this query to the table above, with `2016-04-20 09:40:41.213` as the date from which on it should be counted, the result should look like this:

```
+-------------+-------+
|    name     | count |
+-------------+-------+
| someName    |     2 |
| anotherName |     1 |
+-------------+-------+
```

What I have accomplished so far is the following query, which gives me the the names, but not their count:

```
WITH screenshots AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM SavedScreenshotsLog
    WHERE timestamp > '2016-04-20 09:40:241.213'
)
SELECT s.name
FROM SavedScreenshotsLog s
INNER JOIN screenshots sc ON sc.name = s.name AND sc.timestamp = s.timestamp
ORDER BY s.name
```

I have browsed through stackoverflow but was not able to find a solution which fits my needs and as I am not very experienced with SQL, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention one table in your question, and then show a query with two tables.  That makes it hard to follow the question.

What you are asking for is a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM SavedScreenshotsLog
WHERE timestamp > '2016-04-20 09:40:241.213'
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

EDIT:

If you want "0" values, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN timestamp > '2016-04-20 09:40:241.213' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt
FROM SavedScreenshotsLog
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Note that this will run slower because there is no filter on the dates prior to aggregation.

Comment: I had the same idea, but was also thrown off by the wording of the question.

Comment: Wow, way easier than I expected it to be. Guess I overthought it a bit, thank you!

Comment: Is there an easy way to include `0` values of `COUNT` in the result?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (name varchar(100), dt datetime)

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('someName','2016-04-20 09:41:41.213')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('someName','2016-04-20 09:41:41.213')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('anotherName','2016-04-20 09:43:41.213')

declare @YourDatetime datetime = '2016-04-20 09:41:41.213'
SELECT name, count(dt) 
FROM #TEST
WHERE dt >= @YourDatetime
GROUP BY name
```

I've posted the answer, because using the above query can generate errors in converting the string in where clause into a datetime, it depends on the format of the datetime.

Comment: apart from table variable this query is lifted from gordon linoff Answer

Comment: Try to change your default datetime format and apply the query it won't work. I added the reason I've posted the answer. Of course it's almost the same as the answer above, it's a very simple query you can't have many best practice answers.